# ListView spacing in XAML

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

So, I am having issues with spacing in a listview, Here is my code:

```
            <ListView Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding ChosenDepartment.HoursList}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="100,0,0,0" IsItemClickEnabled="False" SelectionMode="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Width="125" Text="{Binding Day}" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                        <TextBlock Width="160" Text="{Binding Time}" Style="{StaticResource BasicTextStyle}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
                </Style>
            </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListView>
```

No matter what I do, there is spacing underneath the `StackPanel` between `ListItems`. Enough room for two lines of text. In fact, if the text in a `TextBlock` wraps into two lines, it fills the `ListViewItem` perfectly.

I can adjust the margin and `Padding` on all the `TextBlocks` and it does nothing. The only way to effect the height of a `ListView` item is if I had a height property added to the `ItemContainerStyle`. If I hard code a `Height`, it affects it, but of course, I don't want to hard code the `Height`.

Comment: WHat is the `BasicTextStyle`?

Comment: That must be a slightly altered custom text style that I use throughout the app. However, I have deleted the style altogether to see if that changes anything and it doesn't.

Comment: Have you tried using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com)?  It's a great too that makes it much easier to find where an extra bit of padding is coming from (amongst other things).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jeremy's response led me down the right track, but ultimately I discovered another control called `ItemsControl` that comes without all the fluff of `ListView` and was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: thank you for this! I'm using this in a nested listview and just need to show the list, no frills. ItemsControl was PERFECT to get rid of the extraneous spacing, THANKS!

Answer (score 2):

ListViewItems have hard-coded margins inside their template to accomodate the borders and visual indications that are added when you select them (by right clicking them or swiping down  on them with a finger).

If you want to remove them, you need to edit their template in Blend: right click on your ListView then select **Edit Additionnal Templates > Edit Generated Item Container (ItemContainerStyle) > Edit a copy...** and modify the template.